# What happened to Rhaegal?

Tags: plot-explanation, game-of-thrones

In *Game of Thrones* S08E03 ("The Long Night"), the Night King's dragon tore at the one Jon Snow rides (Rhaegal). He falls off of it and we don't see the dragon anymore, is it dead?

Comment: There was a plot killing going on in the latest episode.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

> He falls off of it and we don't see the dragon anymore, is it dead?

## No.

[**Screenrant**](https://screenrant.com/game-thrones-jon-dragon-rhaegal-alive-survive-winterfell/)

> In Game of Thrones season 8 “The Long Night”, Daenerys rides Drogon in battle while Jon is atop Rhaegal, and when they spot the Night King riding Viserion, the undead ice dragon, they attack. The dragons tear into one another as the Night King has Viserion try to pull Jon off Rhaegal's back. Daenerys and Drogon beat him away, knocking the Night King off of Viserion and plummeting to the ground. Viserion then flies off, but Rhaegal has been badly injured in the fight and crashes, sending Jon falling off his back. And though it appears like Rhaegal could have died from those injuries (he doesn't appear again in the episode), **the preview for next week's Game of Thrones confirms that Jon's dragon does survive. A distinctly green dragon flies across the screen above one of Daenerys' ships at the :19 second mark, while Sansa watches two dragons flying above Winterfell at :22 in the trailer.**

[image]

Comment: Perfect answer. My partner and I were discussing Rhaegal's fate, and as the previews rolled I realized the answer was flashed to us there -- just for a split second, but it was there. I had to rewind twice for her to catch it.

Comment: Something I was keenly looking for (and saw) in the preview for the next episode. Maybe they heal like boats can sail in this world.

Comment: Now that episode 4 is out it's confirmed that he lives. Though...

Comment: Well...for a while anyway!